# Inheritance & Lists

Tags: java, generics, covariance

`Class B extends class A`. I have a list of B (`List<B> list1)`, but for some operations I need only class A fields, but `List<A> list2 = list1` doesn't work. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: your question isn't clear. please explain a bit more

Comment: If `B` extends `A` you can access the public fields of `A` via an instance of `B` without having to do anything. Can you be more specific and maybe post an short example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @veredesmarald: consider a method `doSomething(List<A> aList)` and consider a `List<B>`. Now you want to perform `doSomething` on that list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<? extends A> list2 = list1;
```

This means "a list of a specific subtype of `A`".

If you could use `List<A>`, which means "a list of A an all of its subclasses", you would loose the compile time safety. Imagine:

```
List<B> list1 = ..;
List<A> list2 = list1;
list2.add(new C());
for (B b : list1) {
    //ClassCastException - cannot cast from C to B
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generics are type strict , they don't support co-variant types like array.